# Github images load from repo not found

Tags: image, github, svg

I have the following images :

- [right arrow](https://github.com/eugenedrvnk/eugenedrvnk.github.io/blob/master/projects/web-site-layout/img/right.svg)
- [left arrow](https://github.com/eugenedrvnk/eugenedrvnk.github.io/blob/master/projects/web-site-layout/img/left.svg)

both are located in the same folder, but : 
when i open a direct link to left > [it's okay](https://eugenedrvnk.github.io/projects/web-site-layout/img/left.svg)
and when i open link to right > [error](https://eugenedrvnk.github.io/projects/web-site-layout/img/right.svg)

/ the links are the same except for the last word with the file name

Why it happens? Github bug or my mistake?

Comment: Check your URL. If it's correct. Force reload your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Eugene!

By opening both links you've described, it seems the images are showing up, although they are not on the proper position. From what I can see, they are being "pulled" to the top-left corner of the window, which you can check on the screenshot below: 
[image position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSmMg.png)

Try changing the viewBox of the image to see if you are able to see it, or even enclosing the image itself onto another element.

Comment: It was problem with my internet provider, after rebooting it everything start working normal